# Convert H.264 Annex B to MPEG-TS

Tags: ffmpeg, javafx, h.264, http-live-streaming, mpeg2-ts

SO...

I have RAW H.264 video data captured via RTSP in a local file and I am attempting to playback the video in a Java FX application. In order to do this, I need to use Http Live Streaming.

I have successfully prototyped a Java FX architecture that can play a video via HLS with a local server using a local folder containing a .m3u8 (HLS index) file and collection of .ts (MPEG-TS) files. The last piece for me is to replace the .ts files with .264 / .h264 files and in the local server, perform the conversion / wrapping of the H.264 Annex B data into MPEG-TS.

I am having trouble figuring out what is required to get H.264 Annex B into MPEG-TS. I have found the following information...

> "Annex B is commonly used in live and streaming formats such as
>   transport streams..."
>
> szatmary.org/blog/25
>
> "Annex B of of the document specifies one such format, which wraps NAL
>   units in a format resembling a traditional MPEG video elementary
>   stream, thus making it suitable for use with containers like MPEG
>   PS/TS unable to provide the required framing..."
>
> wiki.multimedia.cx/?title=H.264
>
> "Java FX supports a number of different media types. A media type is
>   considered to be the combination of a container format and one or more
>   encodings. In some cases the container format might simply be an
>   elementary stream containing the encoded data."
>
> docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html
>
> "Use the CODECS attribute of the EXT-X-STREAM-INF tag. When this
>   attribute is present, it must include all codecs and profiles required
>   to play back the stream..."
>
> developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html

It seems like I am missing something simple around Elementary and Transport Streams. I have used ffmpeg to convert my H.264 file into a TS file and try to understand the differences. I have an idea of the approximate format differences, but I am still lacking on the details to do it. Does anyone have a link showcasing this or know something simple about how to serve H.264 Annex B data over MPEG-TS?

I am not looking to use a tool, I need to have a custom file format locally where I parse out the H.264 Annex B data and perform the format change in memory, on the fly. I know of a way to use ffmpeg with pipes to accomplish this, but I do not want to have any dependencies and performance is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not a format change. It is a container. There is no need to parse out annex b to write it to a TS file. The TS wraps a PES that wraps a annex b stream. The mpegts format is pretty complex, especially without a third party library. The ts code i wrote and use at work is about 1000 lines of C++.

To write TS code, start by trying to reading a TS file using a hex editor, and referencing the wikipedia documentation. The book [Video Demystified](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0750683953) also has fairly good documentation.

Comment: You're correct, I meant perform the multiplexing / wrapping of the H.264 Annex B into MPEG-TS. I do need to parse out the H.264 Annex B data though because the files I will have are in a custom format (for my company). Minimally, it seems I need a Single Program Transport Stream (http://www.etherguidesystems.com/Glossary/singleprogramtransportstream.aspx) which I guess I need to figure out how to create the appropriate PAT, PMT and PES, etc. I'll post an update when I figure it out.

Comment: See my other question with szatmary's answer for additional information... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564680/manual-encoding-into-mpeg-ts/24565328#24565328